# Laravel EBay API Authorization Code Request Gives Error, Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, ebay-api

[image]

```
$client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request(
        'POST', /*instead of POST, you can use GET, PUT, DELETE, etc*/
        'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencode',
                'Authorization'=>'Basic '.base64_encode('<'.env('EBAY_CLENT_APP_ID').'>:<'.env('EBAY_CLENT_APP_SECRET').'>'),
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'code' => $req->code,
                'redirect_uri' => env('EBAY_REDIRECT_URI')
            ]
        ] 
    );

    $output = json_decode($response->getBody());

    dd($output);
```

I am using guzzlehttp 7.4 and laravel 8.65. All the credentials I am using is all sandbox so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the same error **unsupported_grant_type** etc.

Comment: Error is very self-explanatory. Obviously the `grant_type` parameter is not right. Have you checked documentation to see if "authorization_code" is an allowed value?

Comment: @miken32 yes thats what I am suppose to use.

Comment: Then why does it say it's not supported?

Comment: @miken32 ye literally makes no sense. Lost too many brain cells already trying to figure this out.

Comment: is your $req->code URL encoded?

Comment: have you tried via curl does it show the same error them?

Comment: `'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencode'` - it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you are missing the final `d`. Easily possible, that the API is not able to parse the request at all because of this faulty Content-Type header you are sending, and then when performing its checks if necessary parameters are set, the grant type is probably the first one it tests ...